# Split String and Mix with another string in redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have two columns one is the description and its corresponding tags in another column is a redshift table

```
description                  |  Tags
John Plays Football          |  name, Verb , object
```

I want the output as description with tag

```
John name plays verb football object
```

The one more addition for this is where ever there is a description which contains colon ( : ) I would like to separate the words without removing :

For eg:

```
description                      |  Tags
Des:John Plays Football          |  constant,name, Verb, object

Output
Des: constant John name plays verb football object
```

also need exclude : rule for numbers on both sides of colon to make sure time is getting (eg: 10:10) separated

I have no clue where I will start only

Comment: Hi @Manu Mohan, did my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

You have create UDF in Python to do [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_FUNCTION.html) .

Sample code

```
create function f_py_conc (a srting, b srting)
 returns srting
stable
as $$
  c=a.split(" ")
  d=b.split(",")
  e =""
  for i in range(len(c))
    d=c[i]+" " +d[i]
  return e

$$ language plpythonu;
```

**Note**: Python is dependent on space so may be this code can not run as it may need some change..

Answer (score 0):

you can actually achieve this using Redshift functions, specifically the split part method. I am not sure if this will address the : as well but give this a go and then comment back with what you need to do next. 
The idea is building a concatenated field assembling all the distinct parts of both fields. You can do this as follows:

```
select description, tags,  
SPLIT_PART(description, ' ', 1) + ' ' + SPLIT_PART(tags, ',', 1) + ' ' +
SPLIT_PART(description, ' ', 2) + ' ' + SPLIT_PART(tags, ',', 2) + ' ' +
SPLIT_PART(description, ' ', 3) + ' ' + SPLIT_PART(tags, ',', 3)
as description_with_tag 
from table_name
```

Find out more about this function [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/SPLIT_PART.html)